# fitting model in svyglm

Tags: r

I am using svyglm model, I need to get "AIC" to compare differents models.

My problem is that if I use my model:

```
    Modelo12=svyglm(formula = Asiste ~ sexo + E27 + JovenActivo + hijos + 
    +     jefe + LN_YSVL_sin_joven_prom + aniosed + climaeducativo + 
    +     icv2 + TV + Computadora + Telefono + Cable + Calefon + 
    +     DVD + Microhondas + Aire + Auto_o_moto + Secadora + Lavavajillas + 
    +     Refrigerador + Actividad_del_Jefe + Hacinamiento, family = quasibinomial(link  
    =    
    "probit"), data = Personas.con.muestra, design=diseno_personas_14_17)
```

when I write summary(Modelo12) AIC doesnt appears.

In other hand, I can`t use stepwise, this is the error:

```
    stepwise(Modelo12)

    Direction:  backward/forward forward/backward backward forward
    Criterion:  BIC 

    Error en extractAIC.svyglm(fit, scale, k = k, ...) : 
    svyglm not fitted by maximum likelihood
```

THANKS!!!

Natalia

Comment: hi natalia, welcome to SO.  a quick google search came up with [this note from the author of the `survey` package](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-July/319508.html)

Answer (score 0):

AIC is a likelihood based measure. `svyglm` does not use maximum likelihood fitting, as the error and `?svyglm` tell you. There you also get the advice to use `regTermTest`, which provide Wald tests and adjusted Rao-Scott likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, I think that svyglm use Horvitz Thomson estimator could be?

I see that regTermTest calculate  F, but how can I compare models automatically like stepwise does?

Thanks